# anemone ignore url links including a certain phrase

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, anemone

I am running a web scraper with anemone on ruby and I am giving my server some problems when it visits pages that require a logon.

The pages all have a phrase, say, "account" in the url and I want the program to completely ignore and not go to any link with a destination containing this string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anemone has a [`skip_links_like` method](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Anemone/Core.html#M000022):

> **skip_links_like(*patterns)**
>   Add one ore more Regex patterns for URLs which should not be followed

So adding something like

```
skip_links_like /\/account\//
```

should take care of it:

```
Anemone.crawl("somesite.co.uk", :depth_limit => 1) do |anemone|
    anemone.skip_links_like /\/account\//
    #...
end
```

Comment: so it would look like this?:  Anemone.crawl("http://www.somesite.co.uk", :depth_limit => 1, skip_links_like /\/account\//) do |anemone|